# Geometrical interpretation of a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

It is a well known fact in linear algebra that a finite dimensional vector space of dimension $n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. I am curious about the latter space. It seems in most applications that, this space is pictured with an origin. But an origin need not be defined for a vector space, correct? All vectors may be translated through the space and are still the same vector, only a zero element of the space must be defined for the additive identify. However, reading Wikipedia, they insist that only an affine space has this property. What's the difference? If we consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a manifold that we wish to put coordinates on, then I can see the need to define an origin.

Comment: Note that you really should say that your $n$-dimensional spaces are vector spaces *over $\Bbb R$*. I feel like there's some kind of issue with points vs vectors behind this question.

Comment: An affine space does have have the notion of addition of its elements, in the way that a vector space does (and so there is no "zero" or "identity"). Instead, an affine space is a set on which a vector space acts, as a group of translations.